# where i can add style in this code leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, style, jquery

```
var urlborne = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Gestion-proprete/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Gestion-proprete:borne&maxFeatures=2000&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson&srsName=EPSG:4326';

    var Borne = new L.GeoJSON();

$.ajax({
    jsonp: false,
    url: urlborne,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        Borne.addData(data);
        map.fitBounds(Borne.getBounds());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize your `Borne` geoJson layer without any data but with a styling function specified in the options:

```
var Borne = new L.GeoJSON(false, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {color: feature.properties.color};
  }
});
```

This style will be applied to any data you add later with `addData`.

Comment: ty its working :)